# How to locate dojo DnD handler?

Tags: javascript, events, dojo

Yo, I am just picking up an old project that uses dojo 1.0.2. The drag and drop function is half working and my job is to get the other half done.

The problem is I can't even begin to trace the program. There is a DnD table cell with the following attributes:

```
<td onclick="myclick" copyonly="true" accept="ppDay" dojotype="dojo.dnd.Source" id="src04/08/2011" class="dojoDndContainer">
```

I test it on the browser and it lets me drag and drop, and I see feedback on the drop destination. But the drop event is not completely implemented, which is why I am on it anyways.

The problem is I can't find where the DnD event handler is defined. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implemented in `dojo.dnd.Source`, which can be found in `dojo/dnd/` folder: `Container.js`, `Selector.js`, and `Source.js`.

General DnD documentation can be found in the official docs: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/dnd.html — DnD principles changed little since 1.0.2.